# How to implement If condition based on the based on the result of the keyword in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

In my below test case, If the keyword **Compare system time retrieved at the time of creation with time recorded in the layout**, It should execute the second keyword **Add time to sys time and compare it with time recorded in the layout** It should jump for the third keyword **Subtract time from sys time and compare it with time recorded in the layout** if in case second keyword also fails. Kindly help me out to construct it as a conditional statement in **Verify that the last last modified/created estimate tops the list**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource  ../settings.robot

*** Variables ***
${modified_date_row_1}       css=#estimateTable > tbody > tr.item-name.highlighted > td:nth-child(4)

*** Test Cases ***
Last modified/created estimates should top the list of estimates displayed
  Verify that the last last modified/created estimate tops the list

*** Keywords ***
Compare system time retrieved at the time of creation with time recorded in the layout
  Sleep  5s
  ${get_modified_date_row_1}  Get Text  ${modified_date_row_1}
  ${compare}  Should Be Equal  ${get_modified_date_row_1}  ${date_time}

Add time to sys time and compare it with time recorded in the layout
  Sleep  5s
  ${get_modified_date_row_1}  Get Text  ${modified_date_row_1}
  ${add_time}  Add Time To Date  ${sys_date_time}  01:00
  ${converted_add_time}  Convert Date  ${add_time}  result_format=%b %d %Y %I:%M %p
  ${compare}  Should Be Equal  ${get_modified_date_row_1}  ${converted_add_time}

Subtract time from sys time and compare it with time recorded in the layout
  Sleep  5s
  ${get_modified_date_row_1}  Get Text  ${modified_date_row_1}
  ${subtract_time}  Subtract Time From Date  ${sys_date_time}  01:00
  ${converted_sub_time}  Convert Date  ${subtract_time}  result_format=%b %d %Y %I:%M %p
  ${compare}  Should Be Equal  ${get_modified_date_row_1}  ${converted_sub_time}

 Verify that the last last modified/created estimate tops the list
   Run Keyword If  Compare system time retrieved at the time of creation with time recorded in the layout == 'FAIL'  Add time to sys time and compare it with time recorded in the layout
   ...  ELSE IF  Add time to sys time and compare it with time recorded in the layout == 'FAIL'  Subtract time from sys time and compare it with time recorded in the layout
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the expected results is and what the observed results are?

Comment: How to execute if condition based on the results of the three keywords?

Comment: use `Run Keyword And Return Status` before every keyword and it will return True is it passed without any error else it will return False, after that you can apply if else condition on there status

Comment: Hi @Dev Keyword in the sense? Do you mean keyword title?

Comment: @Poovin  I have mentioned answer below check it and let me know if you have any query further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get status of keywords and apply those status as conditions in your 4th keyword as in sample mentioned below:

```
Verify that the last last modified/created estimate tops the list       

${Status1}=    Run Keyword and Return Status    Compare system time retrieved at the time of creation with time recorded in the layout

${Status2}=    Run Keyword If    '${Status1}'=='Fail'    Run Keyword and Return Status    Add time to sys time and compare it with time recorded in the layout

Run Keyword If    '${Status1}'=='Fail'    And    '${Status2}'=='Fail'    Subtract time from sys time and compare it with time recorded in the layout
```